# ALL Names of God

Tags: tanach, names, shemos-sacred-names

Where can I find an exhaustive list of all of the names of [Hashem](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1196) (preferably שמות and כינוים) in *Tanach* and elsewhere?

Is this too ill-defined a topic to have an exhaustive answer?

Do the 70 in the *midrash* on *Shir Hashirim* count?

Comment: There are opinions ( I think from the Zohar) that all of the Torah is the names of G-d. This becomes practically significant in the first chapter of the first chelek of Likutei Mohoran (1:1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sepher [Shorshei HaShemot](http://seforimcenter.com/Shorshei-HaShemot---Rabbi-Moshe-Zacut---HaRemez__p-6236.aspx) by Rabbi Moshe Zecuto is an exhaustive listing of divine names.  It is an alphabetical index.  Each entry lists the source of the name as well as its usage.

Comment: Source? Do you have a link maybe?

Comment: @Yehoshua What do you mean by source? The source is the whole Sefer, both volumes.

Comment: @HaLeiVi I meant a link to the sefer if it's online...

Answer (score 9):

In one of the Ba'al HaTurim's comments (available with English translation and commentary by Artscroll), he lists all of the names of Hashem.

As Alex writes in the comment, it is in the short commentary on Numbers 11:16, in parashat Behaalotecha. It is [viewable here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11839&st=&pgnum=93), starting two lines from the bottom.

[image: short commentary on Numbers 11:16]

Comment: It's in his commentary to Num. 11:16. He also lists there the 70 names of the Jewish People, and the 70 names of Jerusalem.

Comment: Some of these are surprising! ועד? Or חנק?!

Comment: @WAF I think it's Yodea Va'ed together to make one name (used if I remember correctly in Unetaneh Tokef). And I think it's Chanun not Chenek.

Comment: Been looking everywhere for this citation about 70 names for God. Thank you so much!!!! And thanks for also making the original text available on line!

Comment: Is there a translation of this page for those of us who are limited to the English language?

Comment: @WadCheber 7 out of the 8 lines are just names. Although many of them are very descriptive names, it would be incredibly difficult - and possibly self-defeating - to translate them. It starts off, "...corresponding to the 70 people who entered Egypt, and the 70 nations, and the 70 names of the holy one...".

Comment: FWIW, he's talking about the 70 Elders appointed by Moshe to assist him in leading the Bnei Yisrael. The Ba'al HaTurim thus says that these seventy are "corresponding to..."

Answer (score 7):

Try learning Sefer Shaarei Orah in its new print. In the back of every Shaar is a list of Shemos and Kinuyim that are explained in that Shaar, but it is not the complete list.

Answer (score 3):

According to kabbalistic sources, the entire torah is one very long name of God (supposedly 600,000 letters, each one connecting to each Jew who stood at Mount Sinai).  This is why a torah scroll is pasul if there is a chasar-malei problem (missing or extra alef, hei, vav, or yud).

Comment: Source for this?

Comment: Hakdama to RMBN's perush on chumash.

Answer (score 1):

Read this interesting article: [תוכן הספר](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=40032&st=%u05e2%u05e0%u05d5%u05d4)

Comment: I am not sure why you linked to this page of this book with that search term (perhaps it is a joke) but it looks like there is a chapter very relevant to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10406/is-there-a-list-of-mitzvot-and-their-corresponding-body-parts) in there.

Comment: I looked it up that way because when I was learning this book a few months ago I remember that word being involved (I used it in a Derasha).

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single source with every name. As mentioned above, Sefer Shaarei Orah by Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla is one of the classics and very comprehensive. But once you start dealing with the infinitely diverse permutations of the names it is quite literally, בלי גבול!