# Where can one get the Pri Yitzchak, a text discussing the 613 Mitzvot

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mitzvah, parts-of-the-body

Regarding the Chassidic text written in 1840 entiled Pri Yitzchak that details all 613 Mitzvot and the corresponding 248 limbs for positive mitzvot and 365 sinews for negative commandments.

My Rabbi ([Rebbe Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Goldhamer)) is searching for this rare book and I am also searching to help find it for him. I found [your comments relating to this book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10406/is-there-a-list-of-mitzvot-and-their-corresponding-body-parts/12001#12001) and would like to ask if anyone determined  where the book can be purchased or borrowed from - is it online anywhere? I would deeply appreciate help in locating this for him.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12001/759

Comment: Peggy Shapiro, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Who is Rebbe Douglas? (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5367002#5367002)

Comment: @AdamMosheh vessels?

Comment: @msh210 - Huh??

Comment: @AdamMosheh I was questioning your edit to the question. Why would you write "vessels"?

Comment: @msh210 - Oh, I didn't realize. Gidim are blood vessels, veins, arteries, and nerves. I just made a translation.

Comment: @AdamMosheh a גיד is a tendon or sinew.

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to try winning this one.

Comment: Is this sefer available now online or in print?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the <strike>entire text</strike> first forty pages online [here](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?102156), and then need to pay in order to download the rest. You don't need to register in order to get rid of that annoying pop-up: just click to enter the site as a guest. As you can see, the full title is פרי יצחק: כולל ביאור תרי"ג מצות ברמז, and the author is Rabbi Yitzhak ben Tzvi Hirsch. It was first printed in Vilna, 1834.

Comment: see here for a short writeup of the sefer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12001/603

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_6847_495.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning a class today on the work Pri Yitzchak and other sources . All are welcome:
Todays Class 8/6/20 at 1 p.m.: The Body/Mitzvah Connection
Part 1 - LIMBS of the SOUL
https://us04web.zoom.us/j/667968197?pwd=ZTRzMjZIUVRBT0puRzluRlRxc1hBZz09

recordings can be found on Ladies Who Learn (facebook group)

Comment: Recordings on this topic on my website:

Comment: recordings on this topic on my website: menuchabendavid.com

Comment: Has anyone been able to purchase /download pages after the first 40?