# Correspondence between 365 negative commandments and days of the year?

Tags: number, calendar, mitzvah, tisha-bav

There are 365 negative commandments which correspond to the days of the (solar) year (see Makos 23b; Tanchuma Ki Seitzeh 2). Apparently the prohibition of Gid HaNasheh (sciatic nerve) corresponds to Tisha bAv (Zohar I:170b). Is there a list of the other 364 commandments and their corresponding days?

Comment: If you aren't going to source that Gid HaNashe corresponds to Tisha bAv, why not ask for that too?

Comment: @msh210 this question should not be closed. the one that it purports to be a dupe of asks for a correspondence between negative commandments and parts of the body, not days of the year

Comment: @msh210 please reopen this question, I believe it was closed erroneously.

Comment: I've heard that milk and meat corresponds to Shavuos (brought in Oztar Haminhagim). Some point out that the 66th negative mitzva in the Chinuch is not mixing milk and meat, and Shavuos is 66 days after Rosh Chodesh Nissan. Others say the link is hinted to in that the same verse in Torah has the Mitzva of Bikkurim and not mixing milk and meat.

Comment: Highly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10406/759

Comment: @ichangedmyid That is quite odd, as Tisha bAv is a rabbinic prohibition.

Comment: @Michoel But the 365 days are the Solar Calendar.

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct, therefore what? (365 is the average amount of days in a Jewish calendar year over an 19 year cycle).

Comment: @DoubleAA I think your kasha is on the gemarah

Comment: @Michoel How are you going to assign one prohibition to each date in the Jewish calendar??? The numbers don't work.

Comment: @ichangedmyid The Gemora just notes that there is a correspondence in number "כמנין ימות החמה" but does not (necessarily) establish that there is a one to one correlation.

Comment: @Michoel good point

Comment: @nikmasi, sorry!!

Answer (score 3):

The Maharal in "Tiferes Yisroel" perek 4, explains at length why the amount of negative commandments corresponds to the number of days in the solar year and the positive commandments to the limbs in the human body. Basically he says that the purpose of the negative commandments are to keep the world in order similar to the never changing properties of the sun. "Ein Kol Chadash Tachas Hashamesh"-"There is nothing new under the sun"- Koheles. The positive commandments are to elevate a person's body to be B'Tzelem Elokim. (By the way the gimatria of B'tzelem Elokim equals 248.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer Yishai and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Very interesting point, however this does not answer the question which asked for a list that maps the specific negative commandments to the days of the year.

Answer (score -8):

No. The Jewish calender is a lunar calender, which actually has 354 days (unless it's a leap year or has the extra day in Kislev). The entire idea of 365 days is from the Julian calendar a solar calender, which has no Judaic origins. This is completely coincidental.

Comment: Well, 4 of Shmuel's tekufot is 365 days. This number is used for things like when to ask for rain in bavel as well as birkat hachama. Also, 355 days is when there is an extra day in **cheshvan**. When kislev  is missing a day there are only 353. Jewish leap years are added in order to maintain equivalence with the solar calendar and they've been doing that since well before Julius Caesar.

Comment: @MichaelLevitt [Makos 23b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=23b&format=text): "דרש רבי שמלאי שש מאות ושלש עשרה מצות נאמרו לו למשה **שלש מאות וששים וחמש לאוין כמנין ימות החמה**"