# Is there a list of the 365 sinews?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parts-of-the-body, tractate-ahilot

The 248 positive commandments are compared to the 248 bones ([Zohar 1:170b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44307&st=&pgnum=194)). Chazal provide a list of these 248 bones (Oholos 1:8).

The 365 negative commandments are compared to the 365 sinews (Zohar ibid.). Is there a similar list among ma'amarei Chazal that lists these 365 sinews?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10406/is-there-a-list-of-mitzvot-and-their-corresponding-body-parts

Comment: @ezra I'd say it's basically a duplicate, since it's asking exactly half if that question (just the 365 instead of the whole 613).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I'm not asking about a list that someone compiled to match up to the mitzvos. I'm asking specifically about sources in Chazal that provide a list. Highly related, but I'm not sure if that's enough of a nuance to make a difference, as an answer to that may not answer this one.

Comment: The source provided in the answer in that question seems to specifically state that they used the known sources from Chazal. So aren't you basically asking us to decompile that book and sort out their "original" content from the sources they used?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Technically yes. But the fact that an answer there *happens* to answer this one doesn't make this a dupe; that would be if an answer there *must* answer this one, which it doesn't.

Comment: I can find you a source that 248 is reffuring to limbs and that woman have 252 limbs

Comment: @hazoriz Yep, I've seen Bechoros 45a as well. Interesting source, but sadly that Gemara only addresses limbs, not sinews.

Comment: @DonielF why do you call them bones?

Comment: @hazoriz What, in the OP? Limbs might be a more literal translation of אבר, but in context it clearly refers to bones.