# 613 Mitzvot corresponding to the 248 and 365 body parts

Tags: mitzvah, health-safety-shmira, parts-of-the-body, practical-kabbalah, deorayta

Where can I find a chart or list in English of each mitzvah and which body part the mitzvah corresponds to including bones and organs?

Comment: Thanks. The link in one of the responses doesn’t seem to work. If you are able to open the link that has the translated list and post it here that would be great and very helpful. Thank you very much. Bracha ve hatzlacha

Comment: Welcome to MY. Which link?

Comment: Where is says in the comment “here” and is hyperlinked to the OU site

Comment: You get an error from this link

Comment: https://www.ou.org/taryag/index/limbs/

Comment: Wayback machine implies that this page has been long deleted, and all the links it listed deleted (from a quick check, and can't find anything working in history). Probably not worth pursuing I'm afraid

Comment: So how can I ask people if they know of another English source? If you delete my question as duplicate which doesn’t let me ask the question for new sources because the other one is dated, and I cannot comment on the other one to ask people for new sources because I don’t have these credit in your system, where do I ask?

Comment: By asking this question, the whole topic has been bumped to the top via your question, and thus drawn some attention. Maybe others might have some other suggestions (maybe you can ask a question about Rabbi Jack Abramowitz's shiurim https://web.archive.org/web/20130314045251/https://www.ou.org/taryag/index/limbs/ which might be a web mistake, or at least the link itself? I don't know if that's on topic). Sefer Chareidim is linked in the duplicate, was that not what you were looking for?

Comment: @JonathanEshaghian I believe this is the correct link you were looking for, but it does not give a list of body parts and corresponding mitzvot https://outorah.org/p/6606/

Comment: [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12001/14850) to the duplicate question seems to suggest that the information you are looking for is contained in the work Pri Yitzhak. If you specifically need that information in English, you could [edit] this question to link to that answer, and then ask if that work (or anything similar) is available in English translation. I would hope that doing that would allow this question to be re-opened.

Comment: However, I must point out that I fear the answer to such a question (Is Pri Yitzhak available in English?) is negative.

Comment: Thank you. Going forward how do I create a question and link it to the duplicate?